# Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code -1073741819

Tags: laravel

I got some weird error code after I pulled a project out of my github. My first things I do is `composer dumpautoload`, `composer update`, and `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` whenver I get to a new terminal. This time, I'm stuck at `dumpautoload` as it generates this error.

Here's what `composer update` generated

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

send of 158 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: awobaz/compoships
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-medialibrary
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error
code -1073741819
```

Comment: try php artisan clear and see what error you get so you know what file is causing the error

Comment: execute `php artisan clear`

Comment: execute `php artisan dump-autoload` to clear all logs

Comment: All didnt work, produced the same error code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Old (cached) local dependencies or composer.lock file may causes problem like this. You can try to reinstall all dependencies after remove all dependencies and lock file.

To remove downloaded dependencies, execute this inside app base dir;

```
sudo rm -rf vendor/
```

after that delete `composer.lock` file by executing;

```
sudo rm composer.lock
```

and finally execute;

```
composer install
```

Comment: took me a year to understand this sets of code. I work on a Windows platform and the first thing when I saw this last year was why it doesnt work on the command line

Comment: I have been searching for a sol for months. This worked for me.

Comment: this solution make sense

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, configure `composer` to use the `https` repository by running the following command on the `cli` before installing `Laravel`

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Comment: First didn't work. Second, was using local already. Last, also didn't work.

Comment: Now you added the composer error. To solve this  run `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

Comment: the repo was fixed but the post-autoload-event persists

Comment: if you cloned a project from github, the first thing is to run cp .env.example .env  Then run composer install again

Comment: Also check the content of config/databse.php

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just delete the `vendor`  directory and install the composer again `composer install`

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new laravel project,
and use the new files under the storage/ & bootstrap/cache
to replace the files in the original folders.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and tried re-establishing the dependancies but this did not work for me. It turned out that it was the DB schema causing the issue. More specifically - I had a legacy table named `settings`. Once I renamed this table and followed up with `composer install`, the problem was solved.
I think this is due to a spatie package that creates a `settings` table for itself.