# Error after composer update command: Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

For the first time I am trying to run my Laravel project on newly Arch Linux machine and when running `composer install` command I get this error:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1270
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatiblewith ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1281
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1293
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1306
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1349
Stack trace:
#0 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
#2 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130): collect()
#5 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
#8 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#10 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
#11 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#13 {main} in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line11

In Collection.php line 11:

During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection:  
:offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or t  
he #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/  
Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1349                            
Stack trace:                                                                                               
#0 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illumina  
te\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()                                                    
#1 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
#2 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(110): Composer\A
utoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130):
collect()
#5 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
#8 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades
.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Ill
uminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#10 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310):
Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
#11 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127):
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#13 {main}


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

This is how my `composer.json` file looks like:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^2.7",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel-lang/lang": "^7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
        "laravel/scout": "^8.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.2",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
        "spatie/laravel-searchable": "^1.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Already tried recommended solutions in these two topics, none of them worked:

[Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code -1073741819](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60634251/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-ansi-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-even)

[Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840960/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-event-retur)

Comment: What version of Laravel and PHP are you running?

Comment: @EduardoGalván I am running both PHP 8.1.5 and PHP 7.3.33. With Laravel it is a bit compicated - I installed it a few days ago and said it is version v4.2.10, but `laravel` command is not recognized when I type it to console. When I try to install it from scratch it outputs the same error: `Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255`

Comment: type `php artisan --version` to display the Laravel version you're running.

Comment: @EduardoGalván since the output is too long for comment I post it as an answer under.

Answer (score 0):

Output of `php artisan --version`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1349
Stack trace:
#0 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
#2 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130): collect()
#5 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
#8 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#10 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
#11 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#13 {main} in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line11

In Collection.php line 11:

During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection:  
:offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or t  
he #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/  
Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1349                            
Stack trace:                                                                                               
#0 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illumina  
te\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
#2 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(110): Composer\A
utoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130):
collect()
#5 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
#8 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades
.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Ill
uminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#10 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310):
Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
#11 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127):
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#13 {main}
```

Comment: Try setting PHP 7.3 as default and run the artisan command again to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Add this to the question, not as an answer