# Installing Laravel outputs error 255 (detailed in text)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

For the first time I am trying to run my Laravel project on newly Arch Linux machine and when running `composer require laravel/installer` command I get this error:

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^4.2 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1270
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatiblewith ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1281
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1293
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1306
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1349
Stack trace:
#0 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
#2 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130): collect()
#5 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
#8 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#10 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
#11 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#13 {main} in /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line11

In Collection.php line 11:

During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection:  
:offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or t  
he #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/brankoo/  
Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1349                            
Stack trace:                                                                                               
#0 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illumina  
te\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()                                                    
#1 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
#2 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(110): Composer\A
utoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130):
collect()
#5 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78):
Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
#8 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades
.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Ill
uminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#10 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310):
Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
#11 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127):
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /home/brankoo/Desktop/web/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#13 {main}


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

This is how my composer.json file looks like:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^2.7",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel-lang/lang": "^7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
        "laravel/scout": "^8.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.2",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
        "spatie/laravel-searchable": "^1.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Already tried recommended solutions in these two topics, none of them worked:

[Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code -1073741819](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60634251/script-php-artisa..).

[Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840960/script-php-artisa..).

EDIT: Changing `laravel/framework` version to `^8.75` did not solve issue as someone flagged this question as duplicate. Instead it outputted new error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/ui[v2.2.0, ..., v2.4.1] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfythat requirement.
- Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev], laravel/framework[v8.75.0, ..., 8.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
- laravel/ui[v2.5.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev].
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^2.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v2.2.0, ..., 2.x-dev].
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.75 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.75.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Comment: i would check the php version you have, perhaps an older php 5 for example

Comment: Laravel 7 isn't compatible with PHP 8.1. It does work with PHP 8.0, as shown by the composer requirements.

Comment: @aynber composer is using PHP version 8.1.5, but I have installed both - 8.1.5 and 7.3. How can I change what PHP version composer uses? Or how can I just downgrade PHP 8.1 to 8.0?

Comment: Downgrading will require installing php 8.0 and making sure everything is pointed to the correct version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040685/how-can-i-change-php-cli-version-on-ubuntu-14-04 has instructions on how to change the PHP version on the command line. Just change the version number from what the accepted answer has.

Comment: @aynber it does not work. Already edited my post and added the output to the bottom.

Comment: There are a lot more changes to make to your composer if you're upgrading from 7 to 8, which that answer does not address. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade for all of the changes

Comment: @aynber I am not trying to upgrade anything, I just want to run older Laravel 7.4x project on my laptop

Comment: Changing the `laravel/framework` to `^8.75` *is* an upgrade. I would suggest running it with PHP 7.4, which my other link addressed for the command line. You'll also need to make sure your web server is using the correct version.

Comment: @aynber I have installed php73 as well, but my composer is running on 8.1.5 according to `composer diagnose` `PHP version: 8.1.5 PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php`. Did not find a way to change binary path do `/usr/bin/php73` where my PHP 7.3 is installed. I need to run this project only on local machine.